# Where did I take this picture in Similkameen Valley in 2010?

Tags: identify-this, british-columbia

Can you identify this windy trail please on a mountain slope?  I remember driving a motor vehicle. I do not remember hiking up a mountain to take this picture,  in Similkameen Valley B.C. in May 2010.

[image]

[Helen Mills](http://www.helenmills.me/2011/08/mascot-gold-mine-at-hedley.html) confirms this is Hedley. She wrote

> The 4.5 hour tour started at the Snaza'ist Discovery Centre in Hedley with a short film, then we took a mini bus up the 13km winding Nickel Plate Forest Road with a suberb guide - she talked just about the whole way - explaining the history, the landscape, the stories, First Nation lore - she was fascinating and so enthusiastic and went a long way to making the tour just so great!

[image]

> The winding road up the hill (if only it were paved it would make an awesome biking road!!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Google Lens finds a number of hits for images clearly taken in the same location (using Chrome, right-click on the image and select "Search Image with Google").

The results include a stock image site that has a photos taken "[near Old Mining Town of Hedley, BC, British Columbia, Canada](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-aerial-view-of-similkameen-valley-and-river-and-cascade-mountains-52474693.html)" which narrows it down a little.

The Lens results also include the website of [Princeton Real Estate](https://www.princetonbc.com/hedley), and specifically their page for Hedley, which includes a photo very similar to yours under the heading "Nickel Plate Mine", and with the image alternate tag of "Nickel Plate Mine Road".

Google Maps shows that [Nickel Plate Mine Road](https://goo.gl/maps/fEhJwvNvA4w3b3Be7) is located near Hedley, and shortly after it leaves the main road there are a number of switchbacks that match those shown in your photo.  Unfortunately there is no Google StreetView, nor any other images tagged with a similar location that Google Maps shows, that would allow you to confirm the exact location - but it's very clearly along that road.

Youtube had [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnSKw7ftMjY) and several others that shows similar view and again pretty much confirms the location.